# How to debug ASP.NET MVC bug with database remotely?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I made an ASP.NET Web API project in VS2013 with one controller. The setup uses Entity Framework Code First.

When I run it locally, it works fine. But when I publish it to Azure Web App, calls to the controller will wait for a long time or returns an error `An error has occurred`.

I removed codes which work with DB and it works again.

The plan has 1GB of storage and I want to use it rather than paying for a separate database service.

How can I debug it to see what happens on the server with the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Please go through this article https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/06/introduction-to-remote-debugging-on-azure-web-sites/

Comment: you have the connection string for entity pointing to your Azure database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your connection string in Azure control panel which will be used instead of one in your web.config.

You can also turn on error reporting in your web.config file to see if you are getting the 26 - Database not found error (connection timeout).